# How does vscode execute commands registered in an extension?

Tags: javascript, dependency-injection, vscode-extensions

To register a command in vscode extension, you must import `commands` from `vscode` library and register command inside `activate` function as follows:

```
import { commands } from 'vscode';

export function activate() {
    commands.registerCommand('extension.myExtension.go', () => {
      ...
    })
}
```

How does vscode API integrate the `commands` object in the first place since it's not in the app life cycle and it may even be an older version of `vscode` package?

Does it have anything to do with dependency injection?

If possible, please include simple code to better understand the solution.

Comment: You need a solution? For what?

Comment: Well, I just want to know how this can be done, one way is to use global variables, but I don't think that's a viable solution. I've looked into visual studio code, but I found it quite complicated, so maybe someone knows a simpler method.